# How do I terminate all idle incoming ssh connections?

Tags: ssh

I want to be able to automatically terminate ssh connections that are idle for more than 10 minutes.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open up terminal, `Ctrl-Alt-T`. Then:

- `sudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Set (or modify) the following options:

  ```
  ClientAliveInterval 600
  ClientAliveCountMax 0
  ```
- Save and exit the editor.
- Run `sudo service ssh restart`

---

`ClientAliveInterval` sets the period after which, if the server sees the client as idle, it will send a "keep alive" request. If it gets no response, the client is disconnected. `ClientAliveCountMax` is the number of times such a keep alive is requested before disconnection. By setting it to 0, the keepalive is **never sent** and all clients idle for more than 10 minutes (600 seconds) are disconnected.

Answer (score 3):

Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config

> sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Add in this file the ClientAliveInterval option in seconds.

By the MAN page of sshd_config, that you can check [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config%205) :

**ClientAliveInterval:** 
         Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has
         been received from the client, sshd will send a message through
         the encrypted channel to request a response from the client.  The
         default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to
         the client.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.