# Server is unavailable after client logged out with an SSH terminal open

Tags: command-line, networking, server, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my home laptop (server) and Windows 10 laptop with WLS running Ubuntu (client) but I do not have physical access to my home laptop at the moment.

Until recently I was able to connect to my home server and run some programmes on it. To achieve this I used an SSH connection then used tmux [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session).

This was working fine until my Window 10 laptop 'slept' with the tmux terminal open.

Now when trying to SSH into my home computer I get the 'Resource temporarily unavailable' error. I'm also unable to ping it either as I get 100% packet loss.

The output the the [`w` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92560/list-all-connected-ssh-sessions) does not show any connections.

I have also tried following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137632/how-do-i-terminate-all-idle-incoming-ssh-connections) on the client but I still can't connect to the server.

How can I fix this and use SSH to connect to my home computer just like before?

Note: I had a similar problem (ssh: resource temporarily unavailable) when I first tried to use SSH but fixed it by setting up port forwarding in my router at home.

**Update**

I added the following to the end of my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file based on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1098526/windows-10-linux-subsystem-ssh-client-resource-temporarily-unavailable):

```
Host *
    ProxyCommand nc %h %p %r
```

And now the error I get is `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`